# On-premise, off-premise applications, what are they?

Tags: language-agnostic

When I study about cloud-computing, I usually see these terms: on-premise, off-premise applications. I tried to search them on Google, but no luck. Can anyone please explain these terms to me?

Comment: Wikipedia - Other names: `On-premises software` is sometimes referred to as `shrinkwrap software`, and `off-premises software` is commonly called `software as a service` or `computing in the cloud`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On premises means on location, whereas off premises means remote (in the cloud). For instance if an application runs on an "on-premises" server it means the server is physically in the company. If you have an off-premises solution it's hosted in the cloud or centralized location.

Comment: Being in a bit of a pedantic mood today: The term is ***on-premises***, not ***on-premise***. The two terms have very different meanings. Unfortunately this is a very common mistake.

Comment: Or on-premise is the new on-premises in the English language: [So apparently we lost the grammar war, and on-premises is just called "on premise" now?](http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/brianmadden/archive/2014/05/01/so-apparently-we-lost-the-grammar-war-and-on-premises-is-just-called-quot-on-premise-quot-now.aspx)

Comment: The definition given here is one that is commonly understood, however it has some problems because it uses terms like "on location" and "remote".  Let's say a company has offices and users all around the world, and runs a server farm in a company-owned and operated data center.  Most people would that's "on premises" because it's all company owned infrastructure, but from the perspective of the users the servers are very much "remote".  They are not "on location", at least not the same location as where the users are.

Answer (score 3):

you can always check wikipedia for explanation of technical terms:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

Comment: The wikipedia answers may be a good place to start, but they are hardly definitive.  Checking here to see if there are better answers is not a bad idea, is it?